# How to split tabs into 2 rows in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to split the tabs into 2 rows for a better view.

This is what i mean but in Visual Studio:

[image]

There is no "toggle pin status" button in IntelliJ only a close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on any tab -> Tabs Placement -> Unmark "Show Tabs in Single Row"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disable the **Show tabs in one row** option in File | Settings | Editor | General | Editor Tabs:

[image: Show tabs in one row]

Answer (score 0):

IDEA now has a special setting - **Show pinned tabs in a separate row**.
It works in a Visual Studio way.

[image]